# Utf8 encoding not working correctly in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, html-entities

I have installed [utf8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) module in my node js sever:

here is my code

```
var utf8 = require('utf8');
console.log(utf8.encode('It&#8217;s a way of looking.'));
//output:- It&#8217;s a way of looking.
```

It's not producing same output as php does:

```
echo utf8_encode('It&#8217;s a way of looking.');
//output :- It’s a way of looking.
```

Is it a bug in utf8 module in node js or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`&#8217;` is an HTML entity. If you're not viewing the output as HTML, then you will see it as `&#8217;`. If you want to output a particular character code in JavaScript, use a JavaScript escape sequence:

```
console.log(utf8.encode('It\u2019s a way of looking.'));
```

Comment: your answer helped me though. after using html-entities module, it worked. update your answer and i will accept it.so that it can help others. thankyou.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava I incorrectly thought that the 8217 was a hex value rather than decimal. I've fixed my answer. You don't need to use the `html-entities` module.

Comment: but how would i found the hex value of HTML entity  and replace in my string. because i am getting these string from an API.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava Ok, well you never told us that. If they're coming from an API, then maybe you do need to convert the entities.

Answer (score 0):

it's not utf8 encoding issue it's an html entity issue

here is the code:-

```
 var Entities = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;

    entities = new Entities();

    console.log(entities.decode('It&#8217;s a way of looking.'));
    //output:- It’s a way of looking.
```

thankyou @JLRishe for pointing it out.

Comment: Please use var/let/const entities =